# Regular expression to match sequences of alphanumerics

Tags: text-processing, grep

Any way using grep/awk/perl to match lines in the form

```
*.* = *.*    (i.e.  ac4df.bx5dfd8g = ce5def.dd5f7gdgf )
```

Where `*` means  0+ alphanumeric char?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -x '[[:alnum:]]*\.[[:alnum:]]* = [[:alnum:]]*\.[[:alnum:]]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Stéphane gave you the BRE answer, here are some alternatives:

1. Extended Regular Expressions/ Perl Compatible Regular Expressions

   ```
   grep -xE '\w*\.\w* = \w*\.\w*' file
   grep -xP '\w*\.\w* = \w*\.\w*' file
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'print if /^\w*\.\w* = \w*\.\w*$/' file
   ```
3. awk

   ```
   awk '/^[[:alnum:]]*\.[[:alnum:]]* = [[:alnum:]]*\.[[:alnum:]]*$/' file
   ```

Comment: Note that `-P`, `\w` are GNU extensions. GNU's `\w` includes underscore and none of the non-ASCII letters and is also available with BRE. `grep '\w'` is like `LC_ALL=C '[[:alnum:]_]'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas does `[[:alnum:]]` match non-ASCII letters?

Comment: it matches alnums in your locale, so usually letters in any of the alphabets supported by your locale.